# Updating ComboBox ItemSource for bound child objects

Tags: wpf, vb.net, entity-framework-6

I have a database with 2 tables; `tblContact` and `tblPerson`.  There is a 1-to-many relationship between `tblContact` and `tblPerson` - a single contact can have many persons. I'm using VB 2013 and Entity Framework to create my data binding.

The problem I'm having is the bound ComboBox (`cboPerson`), does not update when I add/delete/change persons unless I move to a different contact and then return.  Is there a method to refresh the ComboBox ItemSource.

I can see that the changes I make are reflected in the underlying object and in the database.

Here is the XAML.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBinding" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ContactView" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:tblContact}, CreateList=True}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PersonView" Source="{Binding tblPersons, Source={StaticResource ContactView}}" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ContactView}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Contact ID:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" Padding="3" x:Name="txtContactID" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Contact_ID, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" Content="Person ID:" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Padding="3" x:Name="cboPerson" SelectedValue="{Binding Contact_Primary_Person}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ContactView}, Path=tblPersons, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Person_ID" DisplayMemberPath="Person_Salutation" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Name="btnAdd">Add</Button>
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Name="btnPrev">Prev</Button>
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Name="btnNext">Next</Button>
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Name="btnDelete">Delete</Button>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind the form.

```
    Imports System.Data.Entity
    Class MainWindow
        Dim _context As ct_dbContext
        Dim ContactView As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource
        Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded

        _context = New ct_dbContext

        ContactView = CType(Me.FindResource("ContactView"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
        'Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
        'TblContactViewSource.Source = [generic data source]

        _context.tblContacts.Load()

        ContactView.Source = _context.tblContacts.Local

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        Dim newPerson As New tblPerson With {.Person_Created = Now, .Person_Email = "test@cambertown.com", .Person_Forename = "Joe", .Person_Mobile = "07", _
                                             .Person_Phone = "01", .Person_Salutation = "Mr Smith", .Person_Surname = "Smith", .Person_Title = "Mr", .Person_Updated = Now}

        Dim currentContact As tblContact = ContactView.View.CurrentItem

        currentContact.tblPersons.Add(newPerson)

        _context.SaveChanges()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click

        ContactView.View.MoveCurrentToNext()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrev_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnPrev.Click
        ContactView.View.MoveCurrentToPrevious()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

    End Sub

End Class
```

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you posted less code. Only the code relevant to the issue would make this a lot more simple to answer, than having to trawl through whole classes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a method to refresh the ComboBox ItemSource.

You could refresh the CollectionViewSource by calling the Refresh method on its View:

```
ContactView.View.Refresh()
```

The other option is to set the Source of the CollectionViewSource to an ObservableCollection(Of tblPerson) and remember to add the new tblPerson object to this collection as well before you add it to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I added this immediately after the _context.SaveChanges() but it didn't refresh to content of the combobox.  I'm going to investigate changing to ObservableCollection.

Comment: The local copy of the tblContacts collections doesn't change when you add a new item to the database. You need to fetch the records again to update the CollectionViewSource: ContactView.Source = _context.tblContacts.ToList(); That's why you should use an ObservableCollection as the source and remember to add any new items to this one as well when you update the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind to a collection (e.g. your combobox items) this collection will not update if you change an individual item within this collection. This is because the collection object you have bound to is still the same (even though the items in the collection may have changed). Your control is not informed of the changes because property change notification is never raised.  When you change to a different Contact you do in fact change the whole object and this triggers the property changed event. This is a fairly common "gotcha" when you start using binding for collections.

If you want a collection to notify you when a value within it gets changed the most common solution is to use an ObservableCollection. This has built-in property changed notification.

If the objects are EF objects and they were created for you then you could consider installing the NuGet package "propertychanged.fody". This grants you the ability to add property changed notification to any class by simply setting a [ImplementPropertyChanged] attribute.

EF classes are partial classes so this allows you to create a second file that you can then use to add property changed notification to.

The result (after adding fody) would be to create a file that looked something like this (you'll need to add name spaces etc...);

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public partial class tblContact
{
}
```

That's literally all you have to do. All properties of tblContact will now have property changed notification. You may need to do the same for your person type.

Using partial classes is a good way to extend the behavior of EF classes that have been generated for you by the designer. If you are new to partial classes they are a way to split a class definition over two or more files so although you wouldn't edit the part that has been built for you by the designer you can do what you please in the file. The names of the partial classes obviously need to be the same so that the compiler knows that they are actually the same class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I'd been thinking about this but since Entity Framework created the objects for me I don't know what I need to change to make the collection an ObervableCollection.  I've got a quiet couple of days so I'll look at the objects that EF has created.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I'm going to explore this today.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page [Entity Framework Databinding with WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574514(v=vs.113).aspx) and I followed the instructions under the heading **Updating code generation for data binding**.

I also had to add

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
```

to the generated class tblContact.vb.

The combobox now updates automatically when I add, remove and update tblPerson.